# Design Editor not showing anything android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

Comment: add gradle file? If your using `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3` change to `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1` and sync again.

Comment: Mohamed Mohaideen AH ,now its working fine now ,thank you for your support

Comment: Welcome glad to help.